# Module import path resolution error in apollo server v4

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, express-graphql

I'm getting  `Cannot find module` error in apollo graphql v4 server.

Apollo graphql server recommends this typescript configuration :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

so that we can use top-level await without async but now I am getting error messages after importing Apollo Server into a Typescript-based Node.js application

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHlnG.png)

I tried to change typescript configurations but one setting was connected to other, i.e: if I set module to commonjs then target cant be es2020